# Can you print format align with a variable in C?

Tags: c

// If I have an int, eg

int num=3;

//then how can I do this

printf(" %nums", some_string);

// to get it right aligned by 3 characters

context: I need to use a loop to print statements with variable alignments depending on the order they are printed, if I cant use a variable I cant do that.

Comment: @user3121023 You won't need `\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's in the `printf` [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some
> decimal integer m) to specify that the field width is given in the
> next argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of
> type int.